# Train output to not be in specific range using brainjs

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, brain.js

I am new to the neural networks and I am trying to train several simple data points. I have training inputs x and y and I want output c to be: c<x & c>y. I tried choosing x and y as features but c was not always in the range I wanted. What other features can I use? I am using brain.js library in javascript.

Comment: What type of dataset you used (or made) to train your model, give some context about that...

Comment: You’ll just need to provide enough training data where c<x and c>y. Then see if brain.js can learn this relationship between the data. But you have to wonder, if you already know the desired formula for the outcome, why do you even need brain.js?

Answer (score 2):

You should transform your data format by yourself. It looks like brain.js will automatic detect normalized data in range from 0 to 1 and will not apply any modifications before training. The article about data format is provided [here](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js/blob/master/README.md#data-format)

> **Data format**
> For training with NeuralNetwork
> Each training pattern should have an input and an output, both of which can be either an > array of numbers from 0 to 1 or a hash of numbers from 0 to 1.

```
const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

net.train([
  { input: { r: 0.03, g: 0.7, b: 0.5 }, output: { black: 1 } },
  { input: { r: 0.16, g: 0.09, b: 0.2 }, output: { white: 1 } },
  { input: { r: 0.5, g: 0.5, b: 1.0 }, output: { white: 1 } },
]);

const output = net.run({ r: 1, g: 0.4, b: 0 }); // { white: 0.99, black: 0.002 }
```